# Move of struct instance in closure and in iteration

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I recently started to learn rust using simple exercises with structs. In this particular case I would like to iterate over a collection field in a struct. However I keep getting compilation errors because reference to a struct cannot be used in a `filter` method as well as in a loop:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct CustomSet<T> {
    buckets: Vec<LinkedList<T>>,
    size: usize,
}

impl<T> CustomSet<T> where T: Eq + Clone + Hashable {
  pub fn new(input: &[T]) -> Self -> {...} // implemented
  pub fn contains(self, element: &T) -> bool {...} //implemented
  pub fn add(&mut self, element: T) {...} // implemented
  pub fn is_subset(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
    for bucket in &self.buckets {
      for el in bucket {
        // error: cannot move out of `*other` which is behind a shared reference
        if !other.contains(&el) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  pub fn intersection(&self, other: &Self) -> Self {
    let mut result = CustomSet::new(&[]);
    self.buckets.iter().for_each(|bucket|
      bucket.iter()
        // Cannot move out of `*other`, as `other` is a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
        .filter(|el| other.contains(el))
        .for_each(|el| result.add(el.clone()))
      );
    result
  }
}
```

I guess my two misunderstandings are:

- why the move of a struct instance occurs in the case of a `for` loop?
- why I cannot use struct reference in a `filter` closure since it is supposed to be mutating only the iterator instance?
- is it possible top solve 2 issues above without cloning/copying and changing the API?

Thanks in advance for any help in understanding this behavior and your suggestions how to fix it.

Comment: `pub fn contains(self, element: &T)` That looks fishy. A method that checks containment shouldn't require ownership. Did you mean `&self` here?

Comment: Omg, I totally did not notice that :facepalm: That totally explains it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Silvio in the comment the issue is in `contains` method that borrows the object. Changing the method to use the reference made it all work.